# How to run code after window opened with "window.open" is closed?

Tags: javascript, window, onunload

I opened a window using `window.open` and go the reference to it. By using `windowRef.window.onunload = () => this.afterWindowUnloaded.emit(this.data);` I can watch the reload of the page, but can't watch the event when I do `window.close` in the opened window.

Any thoughts on how to watch the closing of the window?

Comment: I cannot replicate the problem. `var popup = window.open(); popup.window.onunload = function() { alert( 'unloading' ); }; setTimeout(function() { popup.close(); }, 3000 );` shows me the alert both after 3 seconds when popup.close() gets called, ior when I manually click the cross to close the popup.

Comment: I don't  call the close from the parent window. I call it direcly from the opened window. Try putting your setTimeout on the script from the opening window.

Comment: Only the page opener can directly reference the opened window, so unless you can change the code so the opened window does not close itself, you'll have to rely on `window.postMessage()` to pass things between the two windows. Maybe you can use `window.opener` to get a reference to the opener window, but imho, just switch to using postMessage() for everything. So I would also use postMessage() to replace the onunload event if you use postMessage() for the page closing.

Comment: So in the one script you'd use `windowRef.postMessage()` and `window.addEventListener( 'message', ... )`. And in the popup you can then use `event.source` or `window.opener` or something else to .postMessage() back ( exact syntax may vary, haven't tested this yet. ) before you call window.close().